# Is this Part 23 Final Rule document the final regulation and what are the main improvements?

Tags: faa-regulations

Is the FAA's new [Part 23 Final Rule](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/rulemaking/recently_published/media/Part23_FinalRule_2120-AK65_WebCopy.pdf) the final new Part 23 document? Or will another document be released? The formatting is totally different and kind of a discussion can be found in all the paragraphs.

Also, what are the main improvements in this new version of Part 23?

Comment: The document contains no effective date, so it clearly can't be the final version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document itself is final, but it isn't the same thing as the actual regulations.

The same thing happened with the recent part 107 UAV regulations: [the final rule document](https://www.faa.gov/uas/media/RIN_2120-AJ60_Clean_Signed.pdf) came first, then [the regulations](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=e331c2fe611df1717386d29eee38b000&mc=true&node=pt14.2.107&rgn=div5) were published later. That means, at some point soon (?) the [part 23 regulations](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title14/14cfr23_main_02.tpl) will be updated to include the final rules you found, but I have no idea exactly when that will happen. The Part 23 final rule itself says:

> DATES: Effective [INSERT DATE **8 MONTHS** AFTER DATE OF PUBLICATION IN
>   THE FEDERAL REGISTER].

AOPA has a [good explanation](https://www.aopa.org/advocacy/advocacy-briefs/understanding-part-23-rewrite) of what the rule changes will mean.